# Datediff not returning expected value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

this code always return '0' i don't know why

```
Dim cur_month = DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Now).ToString()
Dim cur_date As String = "01/" + cur_month + "/" + (DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Now).ToString)
Dim sel_date As String = "01/" + (cmb_mnth.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString + "/" + txt_year.Text.ToString
Dim date_dif As String = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, CDate(sel_date), CDate(cur_date))
MsgBox(date_dif)
```

cnb_mnth is ComboBox for Month

txt_year is Text Box For Entering Year

Comment: What is the value of cur_date and sel_date?  Are you saying that no matter what the values are, it always returns 0?  If so, then consider Tuan's response regarding the regional settings.  Consider for a moment that your regional settings were MM/dd/yyyy, using your example, cur_date and sel_date would both have a month of 01, which would return a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that the regional date settings on your computer has month before day (i.e., MM/dd/yyyy), so it interprets 01 as the month for both cur_date and sel_date.